# LINQ does multiple, instead of one, iterations through a collection and then some

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class:

```
public class SimHasher {
    int count = 0;

    //take each string and make an int[] out of it
    //should call Hash method lines.Count() times
    public IEnumerable<int[]> HashAll(IEnumerable<string> lines) {
        //return lines.Select(il => Hash(il));
        var linesCount = lines.Count();
        var hashes = new int[linesCount][];
        for (var i = 0; i < linesCount; ++i) {
            hashes[i] = Hash(lines.ElementAt(i));
        }
        return hashes;
    }

    public int[] Hash(string line) {
        Debug.WriteLine(++count);
        //stuff
    }
}
```

When I run a program that calls `HashAll` and passes it an `IEnumerable<string>` with 1000 elements, it acts as expected: loops 1000 times, writing numbers from 1 to 1000 in the debug console with the program finishing in under 1 second. However if I replace the code of the `HashAll` method with the LINQ statement, like so:

```
public IEnumerable<int[]> HashAll(IEnumerable<string> lines) {
    return lines.Select(il => Hash(il));
}
```

the behavior seems to depend on where `HashAll` gets called from.
If I call it from this test method

```
[Fact]
public void SprutSequentialIntegrationTest() {
    var inputContainer = new InputContainer(new string[] {
        @"D:\Solutions\SimHash\SimHashTests\R.in"
    });
    var simHasher = new SimHasher();
    var documentSimHashes = simHasher.HashAll(inputContainer.InputLines); //right here
    var queryRunner = new QueryRunner(documentSimHashes);
    var queryResults = queryRunner.RunAllQueries
        (inputContainer.Queries);

    var expectedQueryResults = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(
        @"D:\Solutions\SimHash\SimHashTests\R.out")
        .Select(eqr => int.Parse(eqr));
    Assert.Equal(expectedQueryResults, queryResults);
}
```

the counter in the debug console reaches around 13,000, even though there are only 1000 input lines. It also takes around 6 seconds to finish, but still manages to produce the same results as the loop version.
If I run it from the `Main` method like so

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var inputContainer = new InputContainer(args);
    var simHasher = new SimHasher();
    var documentSimHashes = simHasher.HashAll(inputContainer.InputLines);
    var queryRunner = new QueryRunner(documentSimHashes);
    var queryResults = queryRunner.RunAllQueries
        (inputContainer.Queries);
    foreach (var queryResult in queryResults) {
        Console.WriteLine(queryResult);
    }
}
```

it starts writing out to the output console right away, altough very slowly, while the counter in the debug console goes into tens of thousands. When I try to debug it line by line, it goes straight to the foreach loop and writes out the results one by one. After some Googling, I've found out that this is due to LINQ queries being lazily evaluated. However, each time it lazily evaluates a result, the counter in the debug console increase by more than 1000, which is even more than the number of input lines.
What is causing so many calls to the `Hash` method? Can it be deduced from these snippets?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your concrete question is. I think it's "why does `QueryRunner` evaluate the passed-in enumeration more than once"? If it is, then surely it needs a lot more info about the `QueryRunner` class and where it comes from.

Comment: @hvd Good catch, I had an `ElementAt()` followed by a `ToList()` in the `QueryRunner` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get more iterations than you would expect is that there are LINQ calls that iterate the `IEnumerable<T>` multiple times.

When you call `Count()` on an `IEnumerable<T>`, LINQ tries to see if there is a `Count` or `Length` to avoid iterating, but when there is no shortcut, it iterates `IEnumerable<T>` all the way to the end.

Similarly, when you call `ElementAt(i)`, LINQ tries to see if there is an indexer, but generally it iterates the collection up to point `i`. This renders your loop an O(n<sup>2</sup>).

You can easily fix your problem by storing your `IEnumerable<T>` in a list or an array by calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()`. This would iterate through `IEnumerable<T>` once, and then use `Count` and indexes to avoid further iterations.

Comment: Indeed, adding a `ToArray()` makes it evaluate only once.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<T>` does not allow random access.

The `ElementAt()` method will actually [loop through](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1108) the entire sequence until it reaches the N'th element.

Comment: That's a good point, but I don't think the question about *that* particular enumeration.