# Why is a function used in an iterator called so many times?

Tags: c#, performance, iterator

I am trying to play around with iterator functions.

The aim is to get an iterator of all the `Calculation`, `GetCalculations` and to do that, I have a function `GetCalculationFromSheetRowData`, to convert the raw data into a strongly typed object.

It was my understanding that iterators would somehow store the state of the function, and, at each call, resume the loop where it left off.

However, when I profile the program, I see 4078 calls to the iterator `GetCalculations`, which is expected, since the RawCalculations list has 4078 rows, but 4 122 576 calls to `GetCalculationFromSheetRowData`

I have been trying to make sense of this number of calls, but despite my best efforts (it's not 4078 squared, it's not the sum of integers from 1 to 4078, etc.) I have failed to understand the process at stake here.

**Could you please help me understand what is happening, so I can try and fix it?**

```
//The raw data is populated by an other mecanism.
private IList<IList<object>> RawCalculations { get; }

public IEnumerable<Calculation> GetCalculations()
{
    foreach (var row in RawCalculations)
    {
        if (row.Count == 0)
            continue;
        yield return GetCalculationFromSheetRowData(row);
    }
}

private Calculation GetCalculationFromSheetRowData(IList<object> row)
{
    //Takes raw data, as IList<object> and returns a strongly-typed Calculation object
}
```

Comment: What's the result of `RawCalculations.Count(list=> list.Count > 0)`?

Comment: Why you call `GetCalculations` `4078` times and then enumerate the list which size is `4078` there? That would be 16630084 calls of `GetCalculationFromSheetRowData` without `if (row.Count == 0)`. Does it make sense to loop the same collection twice again in a loop? I'm pretty sure that this can be done in a more eficient way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I do not iterate the list on purpose.
My test application is basically `GetAllCalculations().Count();`
In the profiler I see 4078 calls to `GetAllCalculations()`, which makes sense since there are 4078 elements in the list, and 4 millions calls to `GetCalculationFromSheetRowData`, which I fail to understand.

Comment: Is there anything like `async` going on inside `GetCalculationFromSheetRowData` that may be confusing a profiler that's not expecting it?

Comment: @NisargShah - only in integer maths. It's `1010.9308...`, so it's not likely to be a magic number here.

Comment: You're already profiling it. Ask the profiler to spit out the call stacks. If your statements are accurate, then `GetCalculations` should not be the only function to call it. If it is, then set a breakpoint and look at the state while it's being called. Add some object IDs if you have to. Don't debug by guessing where numbers might be coming from if the program's right there.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36386727/1291628

Comment: @ikkentim Spot on, it turns out my question is a duplicate of the question you linked to. Added a ToList() solved the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ does multiple, instead of one, iterations through a collection and then some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386659/linq-does-multiple-instead-of-one-iterations-through-a-collection-and-then-som)